# Upsample function not working in octave

Tags: matlab, octave

I am working on Octave 3.6.4. When I am trying to run :

```
y = upsample (x,4);
```

It's giving me an error : upsample undefined

What to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

upsample is part of the signal package. You have to download and install this package, otherwise the function is not available.